# What is the difference between a marque and a brand?

Tags: meaning, differences, expressions, word-usage

What is the difference between a marque and a brand? For example, why would one use the expression "car marques" instead of "car brands"?

Comment: For perspective, 'marque' is entirely unused in the US.

Comment: Marque is associated with visual style and themes-logos, established styling and badges. It's French origin means that is probably going to be in most popular usage in the South of England where French origin words are more likely to be in use than other parts of the UK which might be more influenced by Scandinavian or Gaelic words. Although it is also more widely used by people with an interest in luxury motorcars and motor racing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semantically in OP's context the two words have the same basic meaning. They both identify either the actual manufacturer *or* a specific product range from that manufacturer.

However, there is a subtle difference perceived by at least some advertisers, and implied by [dictionary.com's](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/marque) definition which gives *luxury or racing car* as likely things to which *marque* may be applied...

The word **marque** (perhaps because of its 'exotic' French origin and associations) is generally understood to be a slightly more 'upmarket' term. Asda/Walmart sell their 'own brand' products, but I think many of us would feel it was pretentious in the extreme if these were to be promoted as being under their *marque*.

*Marque* is primarily associated with 'quality' automobiles, but it also commonly occurs with other luxury brands such as [Dunhill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunhill_%28cigar%29) smoker's paraphernalia, and [Christian Dior](http://news.scotsman.com/features/A-Caesar-of-the-couture.2595113.jp) in the world of haute couture.

Answer (score 2):

A *marque* is synonymous to a *brand* or *model*.  See this excerpt from the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marque) for *brand*:

> In the automotive industry, brands were originally called marques, and marque is still often used as a synonym for brand in reference to motor vehicles.

And [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/marque) claims that they are synonymous:

> **Marque**: n: A model or brand of a manufactured product, especially an automobile.

However, *marque* is less common, as this Ngram illustrates:

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=car+marque%2Ccar+brand&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

This is due, at least in part, to the more refined usage of *marque*, for upper-class or luxury products.  This usage most likely evolved because *marque* looks and sounds more refined than *brand* or *model*, and hence came to be used of more sophisticated products.

Comment: Is this US usage? In the UK, one would tend to say a "make" of car, and use "brand" for things like breakfast cereal where *perceptually*, there's less of a "manufacturing production line" involved (even though I'm sure there is really for doing things like removing nutrients and adding sugar).

Comment: @Neil: I was about to ask whether this was British usage, I know the term, but in my experience, this is virtually never used in the US. We use "make" and "brand" in the same way you do.

Answer (score 2):

I am a graphic designer and as an industry we use the word 'Marque' to describe the logo and the word 'Brand' when talking about the visual identity as a whole, the logo, the colours, the typography, image style, graphic elements, tone of voice etc.

Answer (score 0):

The NOAD reports that one of the meanings of *marque* is "a make of car, as distinct from a specific model."
The same dictionary reports that one of the meaning of *brand* is:

> A type of product manufactured by a particular company under a particular name.
>   • a brand name
>   • a particular type or kind of something

The Collins English Dictionary reports that two of the meanings of *marque* are:

> 1. a brand of a product, especially a car
> 2. an emblem or nameplate used to identify a product, especially a car

The same dictionary reports the following meanings for *brand* (among others):

> 1. a particular product or a characteristic that serves to identify a particular product
> 2. a trade name or trademark
> 3. a particular kind or variety

Answer (score 0):

This practice most definitely has a luxury market history or element. It is used where a stamp or badge would be used to indicate the brand, as opposed to just the name itself of a brand, hence the association with cars and luxury goods, such as "Gucci/LVMH" Rolls Royce Mercedes.

That is my understanding of the difference. Of course these days in a more visual world and with the www, many companies now have logos and the difference is a bit blurred.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like *brand* can mean several things, only one of which is synonymous with *marque*:

- If you say *marque*, there’s less ambiguity because you’re talking about the name of the manufacturer or the badge or logo.
- If you say *brand*, the meaning depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to a vehicle from a design house of heritage and legend that is characteristic in its consistent styling themes and innovative features.

Comment: I presume you mean *marque* here, not just *brand*; is that correct?

Comment: Please be more detailed - what is "it" in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've always used marque as a subset of a brand. So, Sauza Tequila is a brand but under that brand are various marques: Sauza, Hornitos, and Tres Generaciones. To correlate that to the car industry: Ford is the brand; Ford Focus is the marque; and Ford Focus SE Sedan or Ford Focus Titanium would be the specific model.

Don't drink and drive.