# “mark” in generational naming of products

Tags: etymology, history

What is the story behind the word *mark* as a synonym for *version* in products, such as Canon 5D Mark III or Aston Martin DB Mark III?

Comment: Responses to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33493/what-is-the-difference-between-a-marque-and-a-brand) may provide the answer you need. If it doesn't, edit your question to incorporate a reference to it, and indicate just what it leaves you asking.

Comment: @StoneyB My take on the question is: Your linked question talks exclusively about *marque* meaning brand/maker, and not about *mark* meaning version of a particular product. Even if *marque* is the same as *mark*, which frankly is doubtful (at least in BrE), how did *mark* come to mean "version"? Etymonline doesn't give much away there.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The British use of the French *marque* spelling to mean a brand or model, especially of a motor vehicle, is indeed the same as *mark*.  The one that is unclear is *marque* as used in **letters of *marque* and reprisal**. The OED’s etymological entry for *mark* is extensive. Historically, it has sometimes been spelled *marque* with no change in meaning, although there are numerous meanings.  Note also that the Romanic uses of *marque, marca* are borrowings from Germanic into them, and so *marque* is the round-trip spelling back into English again.

Comment: The OED may say "a designation of the stage of development in design and construction of a manufactured product," but it's not obvious how "mark" came to be used for that. And in BrE *marque* is distinctly different from *mark*. *Marque* means a manufacturing brand; *mark* means a version of a particular product from that brand. Even if they both basically mean "version" -- a car from one marque is different from a car from another -- how did *mark* come to mean *version*? I suppose [*remark*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=remark&allowed_in_frame=0) might possibly be relevant.

Comment: I'm with Andrew Leach here: I think the OP refers to the usage as in Mark 48 torpedo or Mark 84 bomb rather than as in Aston Martin DB Mark III. They are distinct meanings, are they not?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek I think he does mean "Aston Martin DB Mark III" because he wrote that. *Mark* there means *version*, the third version of the DB model which the marque Aston Martin produced.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The use of *mark* for make/quality/size/revision antedates *marque* for brand. I didn’t include the earlier citations for *mark* as a make/size/etc, but suppose I could.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well, I stumbled over my own argument, there. I think you are correct, the use is the same, but it is not, I think, in [the question referenced by StoneyB](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33493/what-is-the-difference-between-a-marque-and-a-brand)

Comment: " The first (and only) product line of Continental, the Mark II was developed as the worldwide flagship vehicle of Ford Motor Company.[2] Developed as a successor for the 1939–1948 Lincoln Continental, the Mark II derived its nameplate from European manufacturing practice, denoting a second generation of the model family; Ford would later use this nomenclature for the Mark Series of flagship personal luxury cars." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_Mark_II

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the sense of *mark* that means a particular brand of something.  The OED notes that this is often followed by a numeral:

> A particular ‘brand’, make, quality, or size of an article. Also, freq. followed by a numeral, a designation of the stage of development in design and construction of a manufactured product or piece of equipment, as a weapon, an aeroplane, etc.

Two 19<sup>th</sup> century citations of this use are:

> - 1888 *Treat. Mil. Small Arms & Ammunition* 52 ― Enfield Revolver Pistol, Mark II.
> - 1899 *Kynoch Jrnl.* Oct.–Nov. 12/1 ― Despite the unfortunate failures at Edinburgh and Bisley of the bullet known as Mark ɪᴠ.

Two prior citations that show the evolution of *mark* to mean make/quality/size are:

> - 1669 *Sturmy Mariner’s Mag.* v. xii. 68 ― In regard of the several differences of the length and marks, or Diameter of her Base and Muzzle-ring, no certain proportion can be generally assigned.
> - 1758 *Monthly Rev.* 204 ― The prices of Grinding··and Diamond-cutting the several Marks or Sizes [of plate-glass].

The OED notes that when used with the postfix numeric, *mark* is sometimes abbreviated as *Mk.*

In the specific case of *marque* for motor vehicles, this was borrowed back from the French spelling during the 20<sup>th</sup> century.  Here are the OED’s citations for those, with italics in the original. The most important is the 1958 quote:

> - 1956 *Road & Track* Oct. 5 (Advt.), ― The marque of Mercedes-Benz.
> - 1956 *Road & Track* 14 ― The firm and marque has not actively participated in competition.
> - 1958 *N. & Q*. Feb. 86/1 ― ‘Marque’ is surely a recent borrowing from the French language where it is in general use to denote a particular type of variety of a product, e.g. Frigidaire, Hoover, etc··. The channel whereby the word has passed from French to English is doubtless international motor-racing.

Additionally, the word *mark* was sometimes spelled *marque* during the 1600s, with no change in meaning. However, its use in “letters of marque and reprisal” may — or may not — represent something else. The OED says of this one:

> Etymology: a. Fr. *marque* (OFr. also *merke*), ad. Pr. *marca*, vbl. sb. f. *marcar* (med.L. *marcāre*) to seize as a pledge. It is uncertain whether this is connected with **mark** sb.<sup>1</sup>

The word *mark* itself has a long history, having its English origins in OE. *mearc* and Anglian *merc*, where it meant boundary, landmark, sign.  The OED points out how French adopted it from Germanic languages, and so the British *marque* is just a reborrowing back into English of a word lent to French.

> The Teut. word and its derivative vb. were early adopted into Romanic; the sb. appears as OFr. *merc, marc* masc., Fr. *marque* fem., mark, sign, etc., *marche* (ONFr. *marque*) boundary (see march sb.3), Pr., Sp., Pg., Ital. *marca* mark, sign, boundary. Some of the senses developed in Fr. *marque* have coloured the application of the Eng. word.

The last sentence quoted above suggests that the English use of *marque* has been influenced by the French. The OED suspects that the original meaning was boundary, connecting the hypothetical Old Teutonic *∗markâ* with the Latin *margo* meaning margin.

The word appears in various guises in all kinds of places, from [the **Welsh *marches***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_Marches) to [the old British kingdom of ***Mercia***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercia), all the way to [various Iberian-derived ***comarcas***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comarca).

Comment: Citations are all very well, but all they show is how a word is used. They don't explain how it came to be used. We know *mark* is used for *version*, and while the 1669/1758 citations are interesting, they don't explain how the word evolved from "mark/sign/boundary" into "version". It seems a rather tenuous link, but that link is what the question is asking about.

Answer (score 12):

I think the actual origin of "mark" in this context is from the British Army. This reference describes the origin of the system: [Treatise on Ammunition (1876)](https://books.google.com/books?id=FAcHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA131#v=onepage&q=january%201866%20mark&f=false).

> The system of marking commenced in January 1866. In 1867 the word "mark" was directed to be substituted for "pattern." §1545 states "consecutive numerals will ... be applied to stores on every change of manufacture ... for the purpose of identification."

Another section describes how this looked in practice:

> With reference to distinctive marks indicating the peculiarities of each pattern, the most important is the numeral. This is stamped on the coat of B.L. projectiles made since the commencement of 1866. Very large numbers of shells, however, will be found without any numeral, having been made previous to this date, and many of a pattern previous to that identified by Mark I.

There were various other kinds of markings, but for simplicity they seem to have standardized on consecutive Roman numerals.